# how to download code of azure functions app

Tags: java, azure, azure-functions

I searched a lot about the way to change read only mode. currently I am getting

> Your app is currently in read only mode because you are running from a package file. To make any changes update the content in your zip file and WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE app setting.

I added value in configuration like described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-app-settings#function_app_edit_mode) 
at this path: Platform features -> Configuration -> Add/Edit application setting

but nothing. 
I understood it is not possible so I want to download azure functions app code and edit it locally and after that deploy that again.

I did that:  Download app content -> Content and Visual Studio project -> checked the item and Download  but the file not contains the code. just functions.json and others.

any help will be appreciated

Comment: No code, if you are using java. only compiled files on azure.

Comment: If you use java development, even if you change the readability in some way, it is useless, there is no code at all. Only compiled files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I need to explain it to you.

Only azure functions written by crx can be downloaded and edited. If you are developing locally using the java class library and deploying it to Azure, then on Azure it is actually the compiled file, that is, the .class file. Such files cannot be edited.

My advice to you is to use crx scripts if you want to be editable on azure. If you are developing locally, you need to compile locally before uploading.

Comment: is it not possible to download and see source code in java? I know read only not possile because that I think about download and work with that locally

Comment: @YaffaHarari Many people ask about this. But if you are using java, this is not possible to download the source code on Azure. Unless you are using a crx script.

Comment: @YaffaHarari If you use java, what you should do is develop and debug locally, and then deploy to Azure after no problem.