# Can't download app content of azure function via portal

Tags: azure, azure-functions

How do I download the source code of already-deployed Azure functions?
The person who deployed this function has not versioned it in a repo yet, and the button is grayed out in the portal, as you can see.

[image: Download button is grayed out]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to download code of azure functions app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60600463/how-to-download-code-of-azure-functions-app)

Comment: If this a Windows worker, go to the Kudu console at `https://FunctionAppName.scm.azurewebsites.net`, navigate to DebugConsole -> CMD and click the download button next to the `site` directory. For compiled C# functions  (.cs not .csx) this won't work since all you'll get is .DLLs, but for Node/Python, i guess it's one way to get to the source code. If Linux, go to the bash tab in Kudu and `cat filename`, or just use an FTP client.

Comment: @CSharpRocks no it does not, as I used python which is an interpreted language, not like java where the compiled .class bytecode is used to run the code.

Comment: @evilSnobu Thanks for the tip. But when I navigate to the website you showed, It says I'm not authorized. Perhaps it is because I use a Free tier subscription?

Comment: Do you have at least Contributor rights on that Function App? That could explain in.

Comment: @evilSnobu Well, even when I try to open a function I created with my account, I still get the same error. Also, in the IAM>Classic Administrators, I seem to be set as administrator. I added an "Owner" role to myself just for good measure.

Comment: @evilSnobu, I don't get a denial of access anymore. But the page is blank.

Answer (score 3):

You can download the app content of azure function via FTP into App Service using **"Get publish Profile"** in the portal.

1. Once you login to the portal and click on app service.
2. Then, you need to download the publish profile. Because publish profile contains all the credentials needed for you to FTP into the app service and download your source code. Click "Get Publish Profile" to download. 
   [image]
3. Once the publish profile is downloaded, open the note and extract the following content from the Note.

   - Publish Url
   - UserName
   - Password

[image]

4. Once you have the credentials ready, you can FTP into the app service now. You can use any program you like in order to FTP into the app service. here I am giving an example of using FileZilla Client.
5. Once you enter the credentials, click connect and  expand the **"Site"** directory and right click the repository folder to download it.
6. After downloading, navigate to the folder and you should be able to see your source code.

I hope this information helps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I wish it worked, but when I'm in the FTP I see the `site>wwwroot` folders, but the `wwwroot` is empty after I download it.
Also, I didn't use the publishURL that has a port `443`, as it's of type `https:` but I did use the `ftp://<ftp_url>/site/wwwroot`

Comment: So you publish you function app however your wwwroot folder is empty?

Comment: @GeorgeChen yes... It's a simple trigger function with a few lines (logging and such)

Comment: I'm seeing similar behavior with a Python function app. The only thing in wwwroot is the host.json file. No source code. This question remains unanswered: **How do you download the .zip file for a Python Function App?**. Even showing me how to do it locally would be great. The [docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/deployment-zip-push#download-your-function-app-files) (2018) merely state "When you are developing on a local computer, it's easy to create a .zip file of the function app project folder on your development computer." but give no instructions for doing so.

Answer (score 3):

Since this is still the top post when searching for this problem, I'll add what I found for Python functions:

Following Monika's instructions I was able to ftp into the machine, but the wwwroot folder only had a host.json file. Looking around a bit I found that the actual zip files with the function's code were in the `/data/SitePackages/` directory. Each file's name is a 14 digit number representing the upload date and time (`yyyyMMddHHmmss`). After unzipping the file I finally had access to the function's source code.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use the REST API to download. First log into Azure, then go to one of these urls depending on how your app is configured:

```
https://<function_app>.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/zip/site/wwwroot/

https://<function_app>.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/zip/data/SitePackages/
```

**Warning!** This will zip and download everything in the specified folder. To see what is in the folder before you download, you can snoop around using Bash by going here:

```
https://<function_app>.scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugConsole
```

You can also get to this by clicking on "Advanced Tools" from within the Function App UI in Azure.